# Php beginner: How do I display the user's answers to another php file?

Tags: php

So these codes are on a single php file. What I want is that, I want to display the user's answers to another php file. How do I declare a single variable to a two php file?

```
<?php
echo "<h2>Your Reservation:</h2>";
echo "First Name: $fname";
echo "<br>";
echo "Last Name: $lname";
echo "<br>";
echo "Contact Info.: $contact";
echo "<br>";
echo "Number of Guests:";
echo "<br>";
echo "Adults: $adults ";
echo "Children: $children";
echo "<br>";
echo "Package: $packages";
echo "<br>";
echo "Cottage: $cottagerental";
echo "<br>";
echo "Rooms: $rooms";
echo "<br>";
echo "Nights: $nights";
echo "<br>";
echo "Payment Method: $payment";
?>

How do I display the choices and answers of the users to another php file?
```

Comment: you need to study PHP HTML forms first

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessions

[Sessions in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

I think that is the most simple way